# Locally deploy Maven artifact into a project

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm working on 3 Maven projects sharing a library that I developed as a separate Maven project.

The library project is installed in local Maven repository and I can't deploy it on remote Maven central repository.

Now I'd like to deploy my 3 projects on Heroku, but obviously the build can't work since the library depencency is "private".

I found this on Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies; but this seems related to jars that are not installed in the local repository, so I'm wondering if there is another approach to include in a project a dependency already installed in the local Maven repository.

Comment: Do you want to deploy these artifacts without having to send your library to remote Maven Central Repository? Or you just can't deploy this library?

Comment: Are these maven projects in separate git repositories?

Comment: @LucianoBrum the library is a private project so I can't publish on the Maven Central Repository.

Comment: @roby yes the projects I'd like to deploy are in separate git repos.

Comment: The Heroku guide linked looks like it will do what you need. Committing the jars from project X into project Y's git repository in maven repository format. Alternatively you could look at [git submodules](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#git-submodules).